# Image Segmentation Using K means

Tags: matlab, debugging

When I execute the following command in Matlab 2012a

```
centroids=kmeans(imread('image.jpg'),4);
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using  +
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

Error in kmeans>distfun (line 659)

            D(:,i) = D(:,i) + (X(:,j) - C(i,j)).^2;

Error in kmeans (line 273)

D = distfun(X, C, distance, 0, rep, reps);
```

I need to segment the image into 4 clusters. The image is a CT Brain tumour image in `JPEG` format. The size of this image is `233x216`.
Please give me a solution to cluster this image file.

Comment: What are `X` and  `C` in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the kmeans Segmentation algorithm instead of the default kmeans algorithm provided in MATLAB.

Refer to this [file](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8379-kmeans-image-segmentation/content/kmeans.m). This is the K means algorithm used for segmentation purpose. By using this algorithm my program is working.

Answer (score 4):

The issue could be due to a colour image (MxNx3)

If what you want to do is to cluster the intensity values in the image into 4 clusters you should rather do

```
im = imread('image.jpg');
im=rgb2gray(im) //if you only want grayscale intensities
[idx centroids]=kmeans(double(im(:)),4);
```

If you want to consider colour you could do something like

```
im = imread('image.jpg'); 
im = reshape(im,size(im,1)*size(im,2),size(im,3))
[idx centroids]=kmeans(double(im(:)),4);
```

To visualize the segmentation you could do something like

```
imseg = zeros(size(im,1),size(im,2));
for i=1:max(idx)
    imseg(idx==i)=i;
end
imagesc(imseg)
```