# how do I generate a single partitioned image using MATLABs kmeans function on a jpeg image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cluster-analysis

My question is similar [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379882/image-segmentation-using-k-means) one, except the recommended way to visualise the segmentation didn't work for me.

What I want to do is use MATLAB's k-means code to partition a jpeg image and then visualize the result. 
The code for generating the cluster means and cluster indices of each pixel is available on the MATLAB [help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/color-based-segmentation-using-k-means-clustering.html) but the code to visualize the segmentation isn't included (or at least not in the manner I would like- I want the view a single partitioned image, i.e. all the clusters, represented by the derived mean, are represented in the same image, rather than using the 'means' to generate masks as in the example).

As mentioned above, [somebody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379882/image-segmentation-using-k-means) posted the following as a way to visualize the result, but it doesn't work for me:

```
imseg = zeros(size(im,1),size(im,2));
for i=1:max(idx)
    imseg(idx==i)=i;
end
imagesc(imseg)
```

Comment: How does this code "not work"? Does it give you an error? Does it not give you an image? Does it give you an image that's not what you want?

Comment: You almost have it correct.  What you need to do is figure out which pixels belong to which cluster, then colourize those pixels based on the mean of that cluster.  I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the previous post was doing was that it was visualizing the **cluster ID** as the output image.  You probably want the **mean of the cluster itself** (hence *k*-means).  That's very easy to do and modify from the previous post.  I'm also going to assume that your image is of a `uint8` type, where each grayscale / colour channel spans from `[0,255]`.  Assuming that `idx` contains the membership of each pixel and `centroids` contains the actual colour / grayscale value of the cluster itself, you simply need to do this:

```
imseg = uint8(zeros(size(im,1),size(im,2))); %// Cast to uint8 as image is of this type
centroids = uint8(centroids); %// Just in case, to ensure compatible data types
for i=1:max(idx)
    imseg(idx==i) = centroids(i); %// Set location to the centroid value, not ID
end
imagesc(imseg);
```

Now, if you want colour images, you just have to stack 2D matrices on top of each other.  This can be done by:

```
%// Initialize red, green and blue planes
imRed = uint8(zeros(size(im,1), size(im,2))); %// Cast to uint8 as image is of this type
imGreen = imRed;
imBlue = imRed;
centroids = uint8(centroids); %// Just in case, to ensure compatible data types
for i=1:max(idx)
    imRed(idx==i) = centroids(idx,1); %// Find centroid value for RGB for each cluster
    imGreen(idx==i) = centroids(idx,2); %// and set accordingly
    imBlue(idx==i) = centroids(idx,3);
end
imseg = cat(3,imRed, imGreen, imBlue);
imagesc(imseg);
```

---

## Sidenote

For the grayscale case, you could completely do this vectorized by:

```
imseg = centroids(idx);
imagesc(imseg);
```

I stuck with the `for` loop approach as that is what you seem to be most comfortable with, but you can use `idx` as an **indexing array** into `centroids` and the output would essentially be a map where each membership ID has the grayscale value associated with that cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your help. There's something I'm missing, though; your solution assumes centroids has the same size as imRed but supposing I've only used 4 clusters then 'centroids' is a 4x1 vector?

Comment: @Neil - That doesn't matter.  You're using `idx` to **index** `centroids`, and so the output of `imseg` will still be the same size as the image.  Review how matrix / array indexing works here: http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Comment: @Neil - Also take a look at this post too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22997632/got-confused-with-a-vector-indexed-by-a-matrix-in-matlab/22997867#22997867 .  You'll see why I indexed the stuff the way I did. Good luck, and thanks for accepting my answer!

Comment: Thanks for providing these links, however; I'm getting 2 errors when I try to run the code. The first error happens at the line: imRed(idx==i) = centroids(idx,1); because  numel(imRed(idx==i)) ~= numel(centroids(idx,1)) and a second error is produced if the following is executed: 'centroids(idx,2)' - 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions.' Here is a link to the code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1-f_AEoV8EFOEp3TndKbzdaUlU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Neil - The reason why is because you are transforming your image data into **a single dimensional vector**.  You need to transform your data so that it's `N x 3`, then run the code again.  I don't have time to help you fix this, but do that before you run `kmeans`.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your code. In my example, idx is a vector of dimension 152100x1; whereas imRed is of dimension 169x300, which amounts to 50700 elements, therefore idx can't be used to index imRed, as it currently is in your code.

Comment: Is this the solution?                                                `imseg = cat(3,imRed, imGreen, imBlue);                             for i=1:max(idx)
    imseg(idx==i) = centroids(i,1); 
end
imagesc(imseg);`

Comment: @Neil I made some assumptions which is why that code is the way it is.  I think I'm going to stop helping you here so you can figure this out on your own :) good luck!